# Обращение к элементу находящийся над this

Tags: jquery, javascript

Предположим:

```
$('li a').click(function(){
$(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

А как сделать так что бы `selected` добавился не к `<a>` а к `<li>`???
То есть мне надо выполнить операции над элементом который находиться над `this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().addClass('selected');
```

[parent()](http://jquery-docs.ru/traversing/parent/)

**UPD:**

Если тег `<a>` не является прямым потомком `<li>`, тогда используйте функцию [closest()](http://jquery-docs.ru/traversing/closest/)

```
$(this).closest('li').addClass('selected');
```

Comment: А в скобках parent() можно указать элемент?

Comment: Согласно документации по ссылке, можно указать выражение для фильтрации, но это если вы применили parent() для набора элементов.

Comment: Если у вас тег <a> не является прямым потомком <li>, то тогда используйте функцию closest()
$(this).closest('li').addClass('selected');